# Does my basil have fusarium wilt?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, herbs, basil

my basil has browning leaves and a dark stem and Im worried it has fusarium wilt! I only bottom water it every time it droops and keep it beside a semi sunny windowsill. It does live in a not so well draining soil (which Im about to change soon with perlite) but does anyone know if my basil is beyond saving? If so could I still re propogate it?

Thanks in advance!

[image: The other infected pot]

[image: the potentially infected pot]

[image: some of the bad leaves]

[image: basil I pulled out]